# iStat Menus: show only CPU icon in menu bar

Tags: applications, menu-bar

I am having trouble finding a way for iStat Menus to show only CPU icon in the menu bar. In iStat Menus settings I have only CPU&GPU enabled:

[image]

Moreover, I have disabled all active items for everything except CPU&GPU. Like this:

[image]

However, I still see every iStat icon in the menu bar:

[image]

Any ideas? I am on macOS 10.13.6, iStat Menus 6.21.

Comment: Pure guess, but based on what I've seen in other structures, there's no 'escape clause' coded for if you switch off 'everything'. Switch something on & see what happens. Failing that, contact the developer.

Comment: I am too facing the same issue on Mojave